# date-fns | format date

Tags: javascript, json, date, next.js, date-fns

### Problem

I have below function that formats date string.

```js
import { format, parseISO } from "date-fns";

export function convertDate(myDate, displayFormat) {
    return format(new Date(parseISO(myDate)), displayFormat);
}
```

I have articles that has content such as

```
title: 'My title'
date: '2022-01-04'
```

I call the `convertDate` function using below:

```js
if (articles) {
        for (let i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
            const year = convertDate(articles[i].date, "y");
            years.push(year);
        }
        uniqueYear = [...new Set(years)];
    }
```

My timezone is CEST.

### Error

I am getting error:
[image: Error]

### Expected result:

[image: Result]

I can call the function by using `{convertDate(article.date, "PPP")}` which also works.

Please help!

Comment: You just want to get the year? Why not `new Date('2022-01-04').getFullYear()`?

Comment: i have several articles with different years. i have updated the question with a clearer expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the following minimal example at [runkit.com](https://npm.runkit.com/date-fns) returns "2022", it doesn't throw the error described in the OP:

```
var dateFns = require("date-fns")

function convertDate(myDate, displayFormat) {
    return dateFns.format(new Date(dateFns.parseISO(myDate)), displayFormat);
}

let articles = [{
  title: 'My title',
  date: '2022-01-04'
}];

convertDate(articles[0].date, "y"); // "2022"
```

So the error is elsewhere.

Also, the use of *new Date* is redundant:

```
dateFns.format(dateFns.parseISO(myDate), displayFormat)
```

is sufficient and more robust.

As suggested elsewhere, getting the year from the timestamp can be done using string manipulation, no need for casting to a *Date*. To get the years:

```js
let articles = [{title: 'title 0', date: '2022-01-04'},
                {title: 'title 1', date: '2020-01-04'}];

let years = articles.map(o => o.date.substring(0,4));

console.log(years);
```

If you need it as a *Date* for other things (e.g. formatted month name), cast it to a *Date* once and reuse it.

Comment: even though you think this is not an answer, it IS and answer for me, i was compiling in Ubuntu before, which failed, used Windows now and it works fine, and i have used your recommendations using `string manipulation` and even removed the redundant `new date`.